# When to shutdown Java DB Embedded Database in a WebApp?

Tags: java, struts2, derby

I am working on a `Struts 2 project` which I created from maven archetype starter. I want to use `embedded derby`. Now, whenever I re-deploy my web-app, it gives me this exception:-

```
Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\...
```

What can I do to avoid this? I already know there is a `shutdown` attribute which needs to be true in order to shutdown a database. But, when would be best to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Only one jvm OS process can access the Derby database files at a time. Issue the shutdown when you no longer need the database, or won't need it for a long time. You can access the database after issuing the shutdown, but then you incur the cost booting the Derby engine again.

Also, if you have old OS processes that may have accessed the database hanging around, it might be worth killing them properly.